# When does the callback function passed to process.nextTick() get processed?

Tags: node.js

The Node.js official [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#understanding-process-nexttick) states that:

> the nextTickQueue will be processed after the current operation is
>   completed, regardless of the current phase of the event loop

and defines operation as :

> transition from the underlying C/C++ handler, and handling the
>   JavaScript that needs to be executed.

Still not clear on what operation means. Can someone explain this to me please? Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly when does not really matter much and you should not care about the exact time it is processed (before network packets or after, before timer callbacks or after etc). The really important part is that it is only processed when there is not other javascript code running - it runs at the end of your code

Comment: @slebetman When you say my code, does it mean the block in which my `process.nextTick` is called?

Comment: No. I mean all your `.js` file. The block you pass to `process.nextTick` does not get executed at all until the code execution gets to the end of your file/files. It only gets "declared" or "defined". Then at the bottom of your file js enters the event loop. The current loop is the current "tick", then at the end of the loop it loops again to process events which is the "next tick". This is when js checks for all functions you scheduled for nextTick (the block) and calls them before processing other events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the documentation from that point after is quite explicative:

> Looking back at our diagram, any time you call process.nextTick() in a given phase, all callbacks passed to process.nextTick() will be resolved before the event loop continues. This can create some bad situations because it allows you to "starve" your I/O by making recursive process.nextTick() calls, which prevents the event loop from reaching the poll phase.

<del>The code passed to nextThick will be executed as soon as the current phase ends, hence `nextThick` allows you to append code at the end of the current phase rather than at the end of the loop (as a timer would)</del>

The key answer is here:

> By using process.nextTick() we guarantee that apiCall() always runs its callback after the rest of the user's code and before the event loop is allowed to proceed. To achieve this, the JS call stack is allowed to unwind then immediately execute the provided callback

So next tick appends code to a list that will be executed at the end of the current operation. **Being the current operation intended as the current stack returning.**

So in **pool** phase for example the phase has not to continue to execute `nextThick` but rather complete the entire current call stack (within which nextThick was called) then execute the nextThick list and then go on with the next pool operation, go to the next phase or go idle.

This example in the documentation (along with the explanation there is clear):

```
let bar;

function someAsyncApiCall(callback) {
  process.nextTick(callback);
}

someAsyncApiCall(() => {
  console.log('bar', bar); // 1
});

bar = 1;
// << callback will execute here with bar being assigned
```

Comment: This is the part that I am having trouble reasoning about.
If you take the _poll_ phase for example, The [documentation for poll phase](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#poll) says that when the _poll_ phase ends is if timers are scheduled or there are any immediates set in the _check_ phase and so on. It makes no mention of `nextTick`s set during the _poll_ phase

Comment: I think I understand now. `process.nextTick` is for when you need to execute something **as soon as the current stack ends** and **before the next item in the respective queue of the phase or moving to the next phase**

Thank you for the explanation. Marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes this is how it works. Not aware of any special case where this behaviour changes, but maybe someone will point it out in the future.